# Laravel call method and pass value when got an exception

Tags: php, laravel, function, curl, conditional-statements

I got method in getting the access token and here it is

```
   public $token; //I declare global var to read in every func

    public function getToken(){
        $key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $data = array(
            'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        );
        $payload = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init('https://cgi.singmap.com/token?key='.$key.'&secret='.$secret.'');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
        );

        // Submit the POST request
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $trimmed = $response['datas'];
        $token = $trimmed['access_token'];
        curl_close($ch);
        $this->token = $token;
    }
```

The token only lasts for 5 minutes to use. But in my other method like this which uses token

```
 public function propertyUnitDetails(){

        $unitId = \DB::table('property_unit_list')
        ->select('projectId','unitId')
        ->get();

        foreach($unitId as $res){

        $this->getToken();
        $final_token = $this->token;

        // dd($final_token);

        $request_time = Carbon::now()->format('YmdHis');
        $sign = md5($final_token.$request_time);
        $pageNo = 1;
        $pageSize = 200;
        $url = 'https://cgi.singmap.com/unit/queryUnitDetail?request_time='.$request_time.
        '&token='.$final_token.'&sign='.$sign.'&projectId='.$res->projectId.'&unitId='.$res->unitId.'';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $trimmed = $response['datas'];

        if(empty($trimmed)){
            $this->getToken();
            $final_token = $this->token;
        }

        foreach ($trimmed as $data){
            $inserts[] = [
                'projectId' => $res->projectId,
                'stack' => $data['stack'],
                'floorPlanId' => $data['floorPlanId'],
                'soldBy' => $data['soldBy'],
                'transactionPrice' => $data['transactionPrice'],
                'type' => $data['type'],
                'unitId' => $data['unitId'],
                'floorPlanName' => $data['floorPlanName'],
                'price1' => $data['price1'],
                'price2' => $data['price2'],
                'price3' => $data['price3'],
                'price4' => $data['price4'],
                'custom1' => $data['custom1'],
                'custom2' => $data['custom2'],
                'custom3' => $data['custom3'],
                'custom4' => $data['custom4'],
                'direction' => $data['direction'],
                'area' => $data['area'],
                'buildName' => $data['buildName'],
                'unitName' => $data['unitName'],
                'buildId' => $data['buildId'],
                'bathrooms' => $data['bathrooms'],
                'transactionDate' => $data['transactionDate'],
                'bedrooms' => $data['bedrooms'],
                'purchaseStatus' => $data['purchaseStatus'],

                ];

            }
        }
        $chuncked = array_chunk($inserts, 10);
        foreach($chuncked as $inserts){
          \DB::table('property_project_details')->insert($inserts);
       }
      dd('record inserted'); 
    }
```

When the function is not completely excecuted or the data is not fully inserted, maybe because it has a large amount of data. It throws an error of `datas` index is not found or something from the curl response. It is because I can only get the `datas` based on the token i get manually or declared manually. What I want is that if the token expires, it will run the function `getToken()` and pass the token to the running function in order to avoid interrupting it.

EDIT:
I added

```
 $this->getToken();
 $final_token = $this->token;
```

in my foreach statement because @user001232 said that in every `unitId` result query I got, a new token would be generated. But I still got an error every 5 mins that is because i cant get a new token even if i add that function in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, this will work:

```
<?php 

class NameOfYourClass {
    public $token;

    public function refreshToken()
    {
        $key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $data = array(
            'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        );
        $payload = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init('https://cgi.singmap.com/token?key='.$key.'&secret='.$secret.'');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
        );

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $trimmed = $response['datas'];
        $this->token = $trimmed['access_token'];
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    private function getUnitDetails($res, $attempts = 1)
    {
        // We only allow 5 attempts to avoid getting into infinite loops
        if ($attempts > 5) {
            throw new \Exception('Signmap API Issue');
        }

        $request_time = Carbon::now()->format('YmdHis');
        $sign = md5($this->token.$request_time);
        $pageNo = 1;
        $pageSize = 200;
        $url = 'https://cgi.singmap.com/unit/queryUnitDetail?request_time='.$request_time.
        '&token='.$this->token.'&sign='.$sign.'&projectId='.$res->projectId.'&unitId='.$res->unitId.'';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $trimmed = $response['datas'] ?? null;

        // If the response datas is empty, we're assuming it's because of a token error, so we retry
        if(empty($trimmed)){
            $attempts++;
            $this->refreshToken();
            return $this->getUnitDetails($res, $attempts);
        }

        return $trimmed;
    }

    public function propertyUnitDetails()
    {
        // Grab all of the units
        $unitItds = \DB::table('property_unit_list')->select('projectId','unitId')->get();

        foreach($unitId as $res) {
            $trimmed = $this->getUnitDetails($res);

            foreach ($trimmed as $data){
                $inserts[] = [
                    'projectId' => $res->projectId,
                    'stack' => $data['stack'],
                    'floorPlanId' => $data['floorPlanId'],
                    'soldBy' => $data['soldBy'],
                    'transactionPrice' => $data['transactionPrice'],
                    'type' => $data['type'],
                    'unitId' => $data['unitId'],
                    'floorPlanName' => $data['floorPlanName'],
                    'price1' => $data['price1'],
                    'price2' => $data['price2'],
                    'price3' => $data['price3'],
                    'price4' => $data['price4'],
                    'custom1' => $data['custom1'],
                    'custom2' => $data['custom2'],
                    'custom3' => $data['custom3'],
                    'custom4' => $data['custom4'],
                    'direction' => $data['direction'],
                    'area' => $data['area'],
                    'buildName' => $data['buildName'],
                    'unitName' => $data['unitName'],
                    'buildId' => $data['buildId'],
                    'bathrooms' => $data['bathrooms'],
                    'transactionDate' => $data['transactionDate'],
                    'bedrooms' => $data['bedrooms'],
                    'purchaseStatus' => $data['purchaseStatus'],
                ];
            }
        }
        $chuncked = array_chunk($inserts, 10);
        foreach($chuncked as $inserts){
            \DB::table('property_project_details')->insert($inserts);
        }
        dd('record inserted'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you call the method `getToken()` everytime you got a `projectId` in your loop. Its like this

```
foreach($project_id as $res){
        $this->getToken();
        $final_token = $this->token;

        $request_time = Carbon::now()->format('YmdHis');
        $sign = md5($final_token.$request_time);

//and so on ....
```

In that way. it will get a new token in every `projectId`. the only drawbacks is it will execute very slowly.

And if it is still got the error replace your code like this. Add a condition if empty

```
public function propertyBuildings(){

        $project_id = \DB::table('project_list')
                        ->select('projectId')
                        ->get();

        foreach($project_id as $res){

            $this->getToken();
            $final_token = $this->token;

            $request_time = Carbon::now()->format('YmdHis');
            $sign = md5($final_token.$request_time);
            $url = 'https://cgi.singmap.com/project/queryBuilding?request_time='.$request_time.
            '&token='.$token.'&sign='.$sign.'&projectId='.$res->projectId.'';
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
            $trimmed = $response['datas'];


           if(empty($trimmed)){
               $this->getToken();
               $final_token = $this->token;
           }

            // return $trimmed;
                foreach($trimmed as $data){
                    $inserts[] = [
                    'projectId' => $res->projectId,
                    'buildId' => $data['buildId'],
                    'buildName' => $data['buildName'],
                    ];
            }

         }
         \DB::table('property_building')->insert($inserts);
         dd('Data Inserted');

    }
```

Comment: not working for me. still got an error everytime the token expires.

Comment: what error does the server make when the token is expired? very sparse information tbh

Comment: it says `undefined index [datas]` it is because `$trimmed` does not have a object `datas` because the token expired and cant get a new data @mrhn

Comment: that is not an error on the server you are calling but your code that is not working. To improve this answer we need to know how it acts. If the token is expired usually servers respond with 401 and can return empty response. But if you dont know how it acts it is hard to handle.

Comment: yah but i already called the method every single loop to get a new token to prevent from expiring but still it cause me an `undefined index [datas]`